# Can anyone explain how to solve this problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

A program that reads 3 numbers A, B and C and checks if each 3 numbers are greater than or equal to 20. Output should be single line containing a boolean. True should be printed if each number is greater than or equal to 20, Otherwise False should be printed.

I have tried using "and" operator and got result. Are there any other ways to solve this problem.

```
A=int(input())
B=int(input())
C=int(input())

a= A>=20
b= B>=20
c= C>=20

abc= a and b and c

print(abc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `all` function with a generator expression that iterates over a range of 3 to test if each input value is greater than or equal to 20:

```
print(all(int(input()) >= 20 for _ in range(3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another way:

```
abc = all(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the lowest thanks to the `min()` function.

If the lowest value is >= 20 then you're sure that all the values are >= 20.

```py
A = 21
B = 22
C = 19

min(A,B,C) >= 20  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
a = A>=20
b = B>=20
c = C>=20

sum((a, b, c))==3
```